# Is repeated keywords in alt attributes considered keyword stuffing?

Tags: seo, keywords

For example, I have 100 images in one page, all of them with `alt` attributes in this format:

```
alt="foo pics", alt="bar pics", alt="foobar pics", etc
```

Will `pics` be considered as stuffing?

Answer (score 1):

You're not providing a complete `img` tag so I might be misreading this, but you can't have multiple `alt` attributes like that in the first place.

As for the main question, alt text does get indexed and if you keep repeating things over and over it's not fundamentally different from things like keyword stuffing.

That said,  **this is not at all what the alt attribute is for**.
You should be describing the actual image in there, not cramming a few extra keywords into your document. The alt text is intended to function as a *replacement* for the image in the case that it doesn't load or the page is visited with software that doesn't or can't display them, like screen readers. In those situations, do you really want your images to be represented by "foobar pics"? This is a direct hindrance to accessiblity–one of the primary purposes of the attribute–that would actually be better served by not having anything in there at all.

Comment: No, there's no multiple alt attrs in one image tag, what I mean is 100 image tags with 100 alt attrs